# Python HttpTrigger Azure Function url param as array

Tags: python, azure, httprequest, azure-functions

I have a very simple HttpTrigger Azure function in Python.

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    param_list = req.params.get('param[]')

    for i in param_list:

        # Do some stuff...
```

I'm trying to pass an array object as a url param into the HttpTrigger Azure function in Python. E.g.

> www.somewebsite.net/api/HttpTrigger?param[]=hello,param[]=again,param[]=world

The HttpRequest formats the param as a comma sepeated string:

> param[] = 'hello,again,world'

However what I need is so the param to be type array object:

> param[] = ['hello', 'again', 'world']

Any ideas how to change how HttpRequest type the url params?

I don't have control over the parameters coming in. I only have control over the function. My question is about overriding the default param mapping of setting the url params to dict{str:str} type. This can be done in the requests module and flask. Something like request.args.getlist('param')

Comment: Option 1: just do `param_list = param_string.split(',')`, push your change, grab a beer. Option 2: If you want to do it right look at the source code for the [Python function worker](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker), see if you can do anything about the type that comes in.

Comment: Looking at this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-functions/azure.functions.httprequest?view=azure-python - not much you can do about it.

Comment: Also, shoudn't that be `param[]=hello&param[]=again&param[]=world` in the request? I've never seen an array passed as URL parameter the way you write it (commas instead of `&`).

Comment: Yeah you're correct. This is a typo. However I've now solved the problem using the python library urllib to grab out the url params properly.

Comment: You should post that as an answer and accept it.

Comment: @RichardNixon pls could you share your solution?